# Display Wordpress posts in Chronological (Ascending) Order

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

By default Wordpress shows all posts in reverse chronological order (with the newest post first).

I would like to display all of my wordpress posts in chronological order (with the oldest posts shown first).

I am trying to use a custom loop query to do this, however I cannot get it to work. What am I missing here?

```
<?php query_posts(array('orderby'=>'date','order'=>'ASC'));

    if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


    <div class="postTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <div class="postContent"><?php the_content(); ?></div>



    <?php endwhile; endif;
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

I thought this would be quite simple, although everything I have found to try I also cannot make work. thanks!

Comment: Have you tried array_reverse() on the array with posts?

Answer (score 2):

**Using custom loop:**

If you are creating a custom loop you might want to use `WP_Query` instead.

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query([
    'order'=>'ASC'
]);

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
?>

<div class="postTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<div class="postContent"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

<?php
    endwhile;
        /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<?php else: ?>
        // no posts found
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Using filters**

Or another method is to alter the main loop using filters in your `functions.php` file.

```
function alter_order_of_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_order_of_posts' );
```

I suggest the filter path to avoid changing a lot of your current template.

Comment: If you decide to use a WP_Query solution, here is the WP reference for using ordering parameters https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Thanks @Crisoforo Gaspar 
I would like to avoid the filter in the functions.php file since Im looking to use this on only one page of my site, not everywhere.
Thansk for your code with the custom loop. 
I pasted this in to try but it completely broke the site. Is there something in there that shouldn't be? thanks!

Comment: @RJM I updated the example with the code. With the filter you can use conditionals on the if like: ` is_page` or any other to just apply it on the specific locations. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/

Comment: handy filter for a patch, save me from retouching all the templates, thanks